# How to make a function (f1) run a separate function (f2), but f2 uses the "this" parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

Trying to have an onclick function run another function, but f2 uses `this` and I think that's what's messing it up.

I've tried setting `this` to the overlay f, menu f inside the overlay f, the onclick menu and overlay f caller. My js knowledge is scarce, and there's likely an easy fix, I just don't know what to do.

------html-------

```
<div class="eye" onclick="menu(this)">...</div>
<div class="overlay" id=overlay onclick="overlay()">...</div>
```

------javascript------

```
function menu(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
  overlay.classList.toggle("show");
}

function overlay() {
  menu();
}
```

My goal is to be able to click on #overlay and have the menu() function run.

The error that shows up is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined."

This makes sense, because it thinks "this" is from the #overlay div, and not the .eye div. How do I make it talk to the .eye div?

Comment: Are you looking for `menu(document.querySelector(".eye"))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to pass in the `this` to the call to `overlay` (with `overlay(this)`), and then pass this same element through to the invocation of `menu()` with `menu(x)`:

```js
function menu(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
  overlay.classList.toggle("show");
}

function overlay(x) {
  menu(x);
}
```

```html
<div class="eye" onclick="menu(this)">...</div>
<div class="overlay" id=overlay onclick="overlay(this)">...</div>
```

Having said that, you could just call `menu(x)` directly, as when called from `.overlay`, `this` will refer to `.overlay` rather than menu, and there is no additional functionality of `overlay()`:

```
<div class="overlay" id=overlay onclick="menu(this)">...</div>
```